# Функция sleep при многопоточности в Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x

Допустим у меня есть вот такой вот демонстративный класс:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    stop = False

    def __init__(self, string):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.string = string

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while not self.stop:
            i += 1
            print(i)
            time.sleep(3)
```

Как в данном случае поведет себя функция `time.sleep(3)`? Отдаст ли она во время бездействия управление другим потокам ?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [time.sleep — sleeps thread or process?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/92928/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleep` блокирует поток, но не процесс. Если вы взгляните на исходный код python в файле [Modules/timemodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/timemodule.c#L1052), то увидите, что вызов `sleep()` обёрнут в Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS и Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS:

```
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
Sleep(ul_millis);
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

Соответственно это и означает, что остальные потоки будут выполняться, пока этот будет приостановлен. Можно даже набросать небольшую программу:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


class worker(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for x in xrange(0, 11):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(1)


class waiter(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for x in xrange(50, 53):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(5)


def run():
    worker().start()
    waiter().start()
```

Вывод:

```
>>> run()
0
50
>>> 1
2
3
4
5
51
6
7
8
9
10
52
```

В любой непонятной ситуации читайте исходники

Comment: если вы используете другой StackOverflow ответ почти буквально, то хотя бы [ссылку приведите](http://stackoverflow.com/a/93179/4279)

Answer (score 1):

> Отдаст ли она во время бездействия управление другим потокам ?

Да, как сказано в [`time.sleep()` документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.

Обратите внимание на *"current thread"* ([*"calling thread"* в Питоне 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep))—только *текущий/вызывающий поток* спит. [Связанный Питон баг](http://bugs.python.org/issue23251).

В отличии от исходного кода, документация может гарантировать поведение между разными версиями и реализациями Питона (реализация может поменяться, но без веских оснований, документированное поведение не будет изменено).